# Где находится консоль google-apps-script?

Tags: google-apps-script

Есть скрипт

```
function logMessage() {
  Logger.log('working');

}
```

Как  увидеть результат этой функции, где находится  *google-apps-script* console ?

Answer (score 0):

В редакторе скриптов, через меню - ВИД -- ЖУРНАЛЫ.

Answer (score 0):

В скрипт-редакторе на панели выбрать Вид - Журналы, либо
в самом теле скрипта нажать Ctrl+Enter